# Pointer is not incremented (moved) to expected location or pointer arithmetic is not providing expected answer

Tags: c++

In the following snippet of code I expect pointer to move to next location i.e. current location + `sizeof(datatype)` but not happening unless I type cast to `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int sizeOf()
{
    int a = 0;
    int* b = &a;
    int* c = &a;
    c++;// expect pointer to move "current location + sizeof(int)"
    return c - b;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Size of int is " << sizeOf() << ", actual size of int is  "<< sizeof(int) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Size of int is 1, actual size of int is  4
```

**Expectation:** if I increment pointer of type `int` then pointer should move to current location + `sizeof(int)` but not happening

But it actually works when I use following line

```
return (int)c - (int)b;
```

Compiler warns

```
my-pc $ g++ test.cpp -fpermissive
test.cpp: In function ‘int sizeOf()’:
test.cpp:10:17: warning: cast from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
   10 |     return (int)c - (int)b;
      |                 ^
test.cpp:10:26: warning: cast from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
   10 |     return (int)c - (int)b;
      |                          ^

my-pc $ ./a.out 
Size of int is 4, actual size of int is  4
```

Now I got the output what I expect. I know `int*` is typecasted to `int`. I want to know the reason why it did not worked in first case and worked later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in terms of the size of the pointed object.

So a difference of `1` means the pointers point to `1 * sizeof(int)` bytes apart.

For example,

```c
&( a[2] ) - &( a[0] )
```

always gives `2` for a C array. It doesn't matter if it's an array of `char`, `int`, or some `struct`.

And it's easy to show why this is necessary, given that `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a+i)` for a C array.

```c
   &( a[2] ) - &( a[0] )
=  &( *( a + 2 ) ) - &( *( a + 0 ) ) 
=  ( a + 2 ) - ( a + 0 )
=  2
```

Comment: Thanks I got the point and understood, but how come it works as soon as I forcefully typecast to `int`

Comment: Are you saying you expect 12-8 to give something other than 4? (And saying it works is a stretch. `int` can very be too small for a pointer.)